# Prevent user from entering the same number more than once

Tags: c, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

Also need a condition where's the user cannot input a value higher than 15.
if the user inserts the same hexa again it will restart the "loop"

```
 int matrixArray[4][4], i, j, rowsum, columnsum, diagonalsum;


 printf("Skriv in 16 olika värden för din 4 x 4 kvadrat: "); // asks user to insert 16 numbers to see if its a magicsquare

 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            scanf_s("%x", &matrixArray[i][j]);  // inserts values into the array

            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Error?

Comment: What is the minimum allowed value?  If 0, then there is no need to ask for the 16th input.

Answer (score 0):

I'd define an array of "seen" digits where you store a 0/1 flag for the numbers the user has already entered, something like

```
int seen[16]; // initialize with 0
```

Then, everytime `scanf_s` gives you the most recent input (let's call it `in` for brevity), you check if `seen[in] == 0`. If it is, just store the number in `matrixArray`, set `seen[in] = 1` and continue. If it's not, the user has entered a number twice. Just discard the input, give her a nice error message and continue. That can be done in a `while` loop.

**pseudo code**

```
ok = false
for i = 1..4 {
  for j = 1..4 {
    while (not ok) {
      in = scanf()
      if (not 1 <= in <= 16)
        error("input must be between 1 and 16; try again")
        continue

      if seen[in] == 1
        error("you already entered that number; try again")
        continue
      else
        matrixArray[i][j] = in
        seen[in] = 1
        ok = true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, i've been trying to do what you've said but can't yet figure out how to implemt it. Could you write it down in a little more detailed way... Thanks, im new to C :)

Comment: I've added some pseudo code. Give it a try, implement it in C!

Answer (score 0):

Use the prior values read to look for duplicates

```
#define ROW 4
#define COL 4
int total = ROW*COL;
printf("Skriv in %d olika värden för din %d x %d kvadrat: ", total, ROW, COL); 
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  bool duplicate;
  do {
    duplicate = false;
    unsigned value; 
    if (scanf_s("%x", &value) != 1) {
      printf("Numeric data not entered\n");
      exit(-1);
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {  // look through prior values
      int r2 = k/COL;
      int c2 = k%COL;
      if (value == matrixArray[r2][c2]) {
        duplicate = true;
        printf("Duplicate\n");
        break;
      }
    }
  } while (duplicate);  // reject recent entry and try again.
  int r = i/COL;
  int c = i%COL;
  matrixArray[r][c] = value;
}
```